# .htaccess redirects to example.com instead of www.example.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to solve a simple problem where I am trying to redirect my `www.example.co.za` domain to my `www.example.com` domain.

On the `.co.za` domain I have written a `.htaccess` file with the following contents:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/
```

The script seems to run but unfortunately I don't get the desired result.

Upon navigating to the `.co.za` domain the page gets redirected to `example.com`, which is not my intended result, I want `www.example.com`.

Any idea on how to solve this?

On the the `.com` I wrote the same `.htaccess` code and still haven't had any success.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `mod_rewrite` for that, here is an example that redirect any domain that is not example.com (including www.example.co.za) to example.com :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also check that both `www.example.com`, `www.example.co.za` or any other needed domain is properly configured as `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` in your `VirtualHost` declaration.

If DNS entries point on different servers, your only solution is to create a client side redirection using a simple HTTP meta redirect (on www.example.co server) :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="durée;URL=http://www.example.co.za">
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://www.example.co.za">www.example.co.za</a>...
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Will that work for my make everything `www.example.com` then?

Comment: Do you have `www.example.co.za` and `www.example.com` both declared as `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` ? Your server must be bounded to both hostname for redirection to work.

Comment: I'm not in control of that, is there another solution to this?

Basically all I have access to is the `.co.za` ftp and the `.com` ftp

Comment: If DNS entries point on different servers, your only solution is to use client side redirection, I will update the answer.

Comment: That still only redirects to `example.com` when I want it to redirect to `www.example.com`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128606/discussion-between-simon-oualid-and-barry-michael-doyle).

Comment: There was something else overriding it, thanks for your help.